# ***** gives a Bad Hour error in my cronjob

Tags: cron

I am having an issue Running a cronJob.  I know enough Linux to get me by but I am far from being a Linux expert(Keep this in mind). I am trying to learn how to set up cronjobs, so I followed a very brief tutorial online [Cron Job post](https://www.taniarascia.com/setting-up-a-basic-cron-job-in-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-6484)

I created the PHP file that should just send out a test Email to my account. everything seems to look fine but when I try to save the cronJob in crontab, I get a bad hour message with *****.  I have tried modifying the hours and minutes and I still just get a Bad Hour, or bad Minute message.  this is what going in the crontab *****/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/crontest/cron.php . Could it be an error somewhere else thats causing the problem?

Comment: Are you using no spaces between the `*`? You should use spaces, `* * * * *`.

Comment: That was it, Thank you for the response, Ive been fighting that for the last couple of hours